# Upload image from one NodeJS application to another

Tags: node.js

I have 2 NodeJS applications: one being an back end API and one being a front end application that parses the data from the API. Is there any way to upload an image from the front end application and have it end up in a back end application folder?

Comment: Yes definitely possible.  At a high level, you need your frontend application to post the uploaded file to your backend application.  Multer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) might be a helpful library for your backend to accomplish this.

Comment: yes you need to send files from frontend using formdata to backend api where you can use (Multer or Formadible (https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)) to handle file on server side..

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have install multer
and then

> npm install --save multer

**app.js**

```
const multer = require(‘multer’);
const imageUpload = multer({
      storage: imageStorage,
      limits: {
        fileSize: 1000000 // 1000000 Bytes = 1 MB
      },
      fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg)$/)) { 
           // upload only png and jpg format
           return cb(new Error('Please upload a Image'))
         }
       cb(undefined, true)
    }
}) 

// For Single image upload
router.post('/uploadImage', imageUpload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
     res.send(req.file)
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
     res.status(400).send({ error: error.message })
})
```

i hope this will helpful for you